# Как получить андроиду сообщение от сервера java

Tags: java, android

Есть сервер java. На него стучится андроид, открывает сокет идет общение, закрывает. Но когда сервер посылает сообщение по сокету возникает проблема:
- организовывать и держать открытый сокет все время не надежно (андроид может закрыть сервис) и расход батареи высокий (а если андроид падает в сон, сокет не работает)
- стучаться и постоянно проверять, тоже не вариант: не понятно как часто (не раз в секунду же, а требуется такая оперативность) и опять же батарея.
- нашел вариант через Google Cloud Messaging, но хочется сделать без посредников
(сообщает же mail.ru, что почта пришла или тот же WhatsUp)

понятно, что андроид должен постучаться, оставить "свой адрес", а сервер потом отправит запрос, который слушает BroadcastReceiver на андроиде.
Но как это реализовать в коде на java и андроид не понятно.
3х дневные поиски ничего не дали, принимаются любые идеи.

Comment: Не вариант закидывать все нужные данные в очередь, а потом из Андройд клиента доставать?

Comment: Так будет же задержка от сеанса до сеанса

Comment: То, что Вы хотите называется технологией `PUSH`, но боюсь что на Андроиде таки придётся использовать [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) (GCM в прошлом). Упомянутые приложения наверняка работают на нём же.

Comment: Вы не сможете отправить пакет от сервера клиенту, на это есть ряд причин: клиент не ожидает получение данных; это проблематично если устройство находится за NAT, и т.д. В любом случае происходит установка связи до сервера, и получение данных. Гугл делает это динамически, основываясь на данных (заряд батареи, когда последний раз было активно устройство и тд и тп). Поэтому многие используют FCM, т.к. не хотят изобретать свой велосипед.

Answer (score 0):

Советую посмотреть SOCKET.IO и вот ссылочка https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat/issues/45, где обсуждается как реализовать соединение в убитом состоянии через свой сервис

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна гарантия что клиент слушает, запускаете Foreground Service и бекенд должен "пинговать" (ping-pong) Вас, что бы socket не отвалился. Так же можно слушать закрытие соединения и восстанавливать его.

Comment: Реализовано так, расход батареи больше, чем у экрана.

Comment: Очень странно, как часто пингуете?

Comment: один раз в 20 минут, но тут важно, что сервису не даешь уснуть и он потребляет батарею даже когда просто ждет ....и не получается слушать закрытие, когда сервис засыпает, не срабатывает никакое событие, даже onDestroy()

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено на основе сервиса Firebase (спасибо  woesss за указания правильного направления). Похоже, что прямой доступ не предоставляется, но он не сложно организовывается сервисом firebase.google.com (и все же с посредником :))

1. Прямо из Android Studio можно зарегистрировать проект
   [есть даже видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkZh1iLg7Rg)
2. На сервере в код java добавляется класс, что отвечает за отправку.
   [Подробно это обсуждается тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576705/firebase-java-server-to-send-push-notification-to-all-devices)
3. И потом перехватываем сообщение WakefulBroadcastReceiver
   [пример](https://gist.github.com/Antarix/47c5c8bc70b44af9571e27d174b9cb6a)

Остается только передать ключ ID выданный сервисом Firebase на сервер
и использовать его потом для отправки